# Should using UTF-8 for logging be considered a smell?

Tags: logging, encoding, utf-8

Are there any recommendations/good practices regarding logging and file encoding?

We use UTF-8 in many cases. Writing German software sometimes even your log files will contain German umlauts. There have been occasional complaints that the log files are not displayed properly by some tools. Of course using the right tools solves this problem.

Would you consider using UTF-8 for logging a bad idea in general?

Answer (score 1):

My short answer would be: No. I don't consider it a bad idea *in general*. Quite the opposite: UTF-8 is the most spread encoding!

When writing german software (or any other software in a language that does contain non-UTF8 characters) there are few possibilities:

- simply don't use non-UTF8 characters. German umlauts may be written as `ae` instead of `ä` for example, but for other non-UTF8 characters in other languages there are no other ways to write them
- write log outputs in english
- as you already mentioned: use the right tools
- encode your log files with another charset

Personally (and writing German software as well), I tend to write as much in english as possible, as it avoids such problems in many circumstances. Unless the customer wants the log output to be written in German, of course.
Except for one case I would'nt encode the log files with another charset, because UTF-8 is the most spread encoding. The one case mentioned would be, if there is an arrangement to use another charset with all the other people involved in the project. This may get tricky and has a certain possibility to fail when (for example) new developers join the project and it isn't documented that logfiles are not encoded with UTF-8.